# Second order Taylor expansion to solve system of equations

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, na.numerical-analysis

Suppose you need to solve $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $m,n>1$. Newton's method relies on first order Taylor expansion of f. Where can I find details of analogous method using second order Taylor expansion? I found at least a dozen numerical analysis books which mention this method, but give no details or applications

Comment: I'd be interested in learning about when using a second order technique might be useful and better than a first order method (Newton or Picard). It seems to me that higher methods are more prone to instabilities.

Comment: @Deane: yes, methods with higher-order convergence tend to be finicky in that if you're a teeny bit far away from the solution you want to converge to, there is a great chance of converging to a different solution, or worse, diverge.

Comment: @Yaroslav: Again, as I mentioned in your m.SE question, you need to figure out first what it means to invert a rank-3 tensor before you can figure out how to generalize Halley to multivariate nonlinear systems. Otherwise, there's Householder's method, but since multiplication of vectors, matrices and rank-3 tensors is noncommutative, you need to look at how to multiply the terms to get to your multivariate generalization.

Comment: Halley's method is just one particular form of second order method. Alternative would be to use quadratic formula. Are you sure I just need to take Halley's formula and "plug it in"?

Comment: Both Halley and Householder are cubically convergent methods that are derived from the truncation up to the quadratic term of the multivariate Taylor series. There's another formula due to Halley that requires square roots in the univariate case, so I won't talk more about it because generalizing that is a whole new can of worms.

Comment: A minor caution about a difference in terminology: in optimization, Newton-type methods are generally called second-order, while here it seems they are called first-order, because essentially instead of solving $\min g(x)$, one is considering the associated problem of solving $f(x) := \nabla g(x) = 0$.

Comment: Since "order" is so overloaded a word :P , that's the reason I prefer "quadratically/cubically convergent" and "first/second order Taylor expansion" when discussing such iterative methods. :)

Answer (score 3):

The single-variable version of what you are looking for is called Halley's method.  (See, for example, MathWorld's article on [Halley's method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HalleysMethod.html).)  Maybe there's a fairly straightforward way to generalize it to multivariable functions.  Or, if nothing else, this gives you another search term.

Comment: It seems like Halley's method is a hybrid between 1st order Taylor expansion and second order Taylor expansion http://books.google.com/books?id=SzJ1G6QIqjEC&pg=PA1286&dq=Halley's+method&hl=en&ei=jrenTNDRFJG-sAP1hr2HDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Halley's%20method&f=false

Answer (score 1):

I haven't gotten around to downloading and reading it (and I'm wondering how I missed this when I was searching for results related to Halley's method), but apparently a [multivariate version of the Halley iteration](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/3147.3162) has already been developed decades ago. Maybe this might be of use.